# ImageButton doesn't work in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I'm developing an app using Fragments and I have an ImageButton on one of my Fragments. It's supposed to ask the user if they want to save what they've entered in an EditText and then save it to a SQLiteDatabase if they press enter. This all worked fine when this Fragment was an Activity, except that I didn't have to override onKeyDown. Now that I've moved it to a Fragment, the ImageButton does nothing. What am I missing? Here's the code:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/stitchnotes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/video_content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/actions_file_save_as_icon" />
```

I'm using the technique from [here](http://useranswer.com/answer/fragment-which-callback-invoked-when-press-back-button-customize-it/) to override the onKeyDown method in the Activity that extends Fragment Activity:

```
public class StitchList extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    DetailFrag frag = new DetailFrag();
    frag.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    return false;
}
```

and then defining onKeyDown in my Fragment:

```
public class DetailFrag extends Fragment {
public static boolean Edited = false;
public AlertDialog.Builder builder;
public AlertDialog alert;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailfragment, container, false);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
            "danielbk.ttf");

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to save your Notes?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });

    alert = builder.create();

    final EditText notes = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.stitchnotes);
    notes.setTypeface(font);
    notes.setTextSize(12);

    ImageButton savebutton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    savebutton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Notes = notes.getText().toString();
            Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(STITCHES_URI, rowID);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("stitchnotes", Notes);
            getActivity().getContentResolver().update(updateUri,values,null,null);
        }
    });
    notes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            Edited = true;

        }
    });

    return view;
}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0
            && Edited) {
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now in your `onKeyDown` method in the `FragmentActivity` it is going to create a new Fragment every time a key is pressed, but it never adds it to the `FragmentManager`

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    // Creates a new DetailFrag
    DetailFrag frag = new DetailFrag();
    // Call the onKeyDown in the new Fragment
    frag.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    return false;
}
```

You want to get the existing `DetailFrag` from the `FragmentManager`, something like:

```
DetailFrag f = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyTag");
```

or

```
DetailFrag f = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManger().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

once you have the fragment you can call the `onKeyDown` method.

Also, in your `DetailFrag` if you want to pop up the alert when the `ImageButton` is clicked you need to call `alert.show()` in the `onClick` method.

```
savebutton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        alert.show();
        ....
    }
});
```

And then the methods that update your database would go in the `onClick` method of the `PositiveButton` in the `Dialog`, right now it is just calling `dialog.cancel()` which just dis

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String Notes = notes.getText().toString();
                Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(STITCHES_URI, rowID);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("stitchnotes", Notes);
                getActivity().getContentResolver().update(updateUri,values,null,null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This all makes sense. However, when I use getFragmentManager() as you suggest in my FragmentActivity, I get "Cannot cast from Fragment to DetailFrag". I don't understand why, since DetailFrag extends Fragment. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I know the answer. I was using the Support Library. If I use android.app.Fragment, the problem goes away. However, in my ListFragment I then get a problem with getLoaderManager().initLoader where I initialize my CursorLoader. At any rate, I'd prefer to use the Support Library for backwards compatibility, so if anyone knows how to get around this cast issue, I'd be most grateful

Comment: Ah, getSupportFragmentManager() does the trick. On to the next issue! And thank you, antew!

Comment: Hey Melanie, glad you got it figured out.  I should've put a note about SupportFragmentManager!

Comment: Nah, that's ok, antew. I didn't say I was using the Support Library. I have found it to be a challenge because I keep forgetting that's what I'm doing. :/